# What does the EC2 command line say when a machine won't start?

Tags: command-line, amazon-ec2

When starting an instance on Amazon EC2,  how would I detect a failure,  for instance,  if there's no machine available to fulfill my request?     I'm using one of the less-common machine types and am concerned it won't start up,  but am having trouble finding out what message to look for to detect this.

I'm using the EC2 commandline tools to do this.   I know I can look for 'running' when I do ec2-describe-instance to see if the machine is up,  but don't know what to look for to see if the startup failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe more about the possible reasons for failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `ec2-start-instances` only returns you `stopped pending`, and as you say you need to use [`ec2-describe-instances`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html) to retrieve the state.

For that, you have a couple of choices; you can either use a loop to check for `instance-state-name`, looking for a result of `running` or `stopped`; alternatively you could look at either the `reason` or `state-reason-code` fields; unfortunately you'll need to trigger the failure you're worried about, to obtain the values that indicate failure.

The batch file I use to wait for a successful startup (fill in the underscores):

```
@echo off
set EC2_HOME=C:\tools\ec2-api-tools
set EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=C:\_\pk-_.pem
set EC2_CERT=C:\_\cert-_.pem
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
%EC2_HOME%\bin\ec2-start-instances i-_
:docheck
%EC2_HOME%\bin\ec2-describe-instances | C:\tools\gnuwin32\bin\grep.exe -c stopped > %EC2_HOME%\temp.txt
findstr /m "1" %EC2_HOME%\temp.txt > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (c:\tools\gnuwin32\bin\echo -n "."
goto docheck)
del temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

ec2-start-instances will return you the previous state (after last command to instance) and the current state (after your command). ec2-stop instances does the same thing. THE PROBLEM IS, if you are scripting and you use *-start-* on a 'stopping' instance -OR- you use a *-stop-* on a 'pending' instance. These will cause exceptions in the command line tool and NASTILY exit your scripts all the way to the original console (VERY BAD BEHVIOR, AMAZON). So you have to go all the way through parsing the ec2-describe-instances [instance-id] result.  HOWVER, that still leaves you vulnerable to that tiny little bit of time between when you GET the status from your instance and you APPLY A COMMAND. If someone else, or Amazon, puts you into pending or stopping, and you then do 'stop' or 'start respectively, your script will break. I really don't know how to catch such an exception with script. Bad Amazon AWS, BAD DOG!